# turing machine accept and reject state

Tags: computer-science, automata, turing-machines

I am pretty new to Turing Machines and I am trying to understand the basic things first...so my question is , would this machine accept `all words ending in 'a'` ? if that's the case would the REJECT state be `all string without 'a' and ending with 'b'` ?

[image]

Comment: Based on what you wrote, you're asking about Turing machines with two different halting states, an accepting state $q_{\text{ACCEPT}}$ and a rejecting state $q_{\text{REJECT}}$. But, the diagram you include only has a single halt state. Without knowing exactly how your textbook/course defines a Turing machine, it will be hard to answer this question. So, what's the formal definition that you're working with?

Answer (score -1):

This Turing-machine's head will move to right on encounter of every **'a'** and whenever it find the **'b'**, this will change it to **'a'** and move to left and halt.

(a,a,R) : says that if tape symbol is **'a'** keep it **'a'** only and move R(Right).

(b,a,L) : says that if tape symbol is **'b'** make it **'a'** and move L(left) with halt.

So, this TM will accept all string ending with **'b'**, as it moves to halt state if and only if **'b'** comes.

I hope this will help. good luck :)